# jekyll compilation error on upgrade to 0.12.0

Tags: jekyll

Since I have updated Jekyl to `0.12.0` my site doesn't compile anymore. Everywhere I have code like this, looping through post and filtering a category it fails

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts reversed  %}
  {% if post.category[0] == "about" %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{base_path}}{{post.url}}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is the error message that I get:

```
Liquid Exception: undefined method `gsub' for ["about"]:Array in 2012-09-20-about.md
```

If I remove `Jekyll 0.12.0` then everything works again.

Has something changed in a drastic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must have some posts without any categories defined?

I believe Jekyll 0.12.0 made the standards for error catching higher.  So if a post has no categories, the Ruby command `post.category[0] == about` doesn't throw `FALSE`, it throws `NA` (or something like that).  Before, Jekyll would just ignore this (presumably treating it as `FALSE`), which isn't really the best behavior.

My guess is that you should rewrite the command to be more explicit, i.e. if category[0] is not empty AND has value "about".  Consider simply adding the extra `if` statement before your command:

```
{% if defined?(post.category[0]) %}
```

To check that you're not making an invalid comparison first.

Comment: Didn't know about that, thanks for the info :). As for why it stopped working i still don't know, it's rolling again now ...

Comment: Actually you were right. It's because some of my post don't have a category.

Comment: Cool, good to hear that it's working.  Have you been able to get it to run successfully even without a category using the trick above?

Comment: If I keep Jekyll to 0.11.2 yes :). Otherwise no, I will have to change the architecture of the site and move the post without category to pages. The site is hosted on Github  and they now run Jekyll 0.12.0

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I can't reproduce the error here. If you change it to

```
{% if post.category contains "about" %}
```

does it work?